# Help with mathematic operands in class (c#)

Tags: c#, class, operands

```
public class Racional<T>
{
    private T nominator;
    private T denominator;
    public T Nominator
    {
        get { return nominator; }
        set { nominator = value; }
    }
    public T Denominator
    {
        get { return denominator; }
        set { denominator = value; }
    }
    public Racional(T nominator, T denominator)
    {
        this.nominator = nominator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
    public static Racional<int> operator *(Racional<int> a, Racional<int> b)
    {
        return ((int)(a.nominator + b.nominator, a.denominator + b.denominator));
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + this.nominator + " " + this.denominator + ")";
    }
}
```

I'm interested in this part :

```
public static Racional<int> operator *(Racional<int> a, Racional<int> b)
{
    return ((int)(a.nominator + b.nominator,  a.denominator + b.denominator));
}
```

What's wrong:

> One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

How I can normaly code this part for mathematic operations?

Comment: BTW is this a homework or you are going to use it in production code? Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational%28v=vs.93%29.aspx

Comment: You might want to change the class name to Rational...

Comment: Why are you creating a class that is handled by the framework out of the box?  If this is homework this is a horrible way of doing this.

Comment: @Roy: I assume it's in language other than English. At least he posted his *actual* code, rather than risk irrelevant typographical errors appearing.

Comment: Since it looks like what you really want is a rational of int all along, why are you even using generics?

Comment: @Felipe: To allow decimal, BigInteger and/or float rationals, maybe?

Comment: Hold on a moment here, you're saying that 1/2 * 2/3 = 3/5 ? This code not only doesn't compile, it doesn't make any sense. And you're saying that there are rationals that have arbitrary types as the numerator and denominator?  **Why is this generic at all**?  A rational is defined as the ratio of two integers. You could have integers, strings, exceptions, and so on. This code doesn't make any sense to me. Can you explain?

Comment: This is homework(lab), more I don't know English enough

Comment: @Cody & Sergio: Nominator and Denominator are Spanish words?? :-)

Comment: @Eric: I assume he wants to be able to use Int16, Int32, Int64 as possible numerator and denominator types.

Comment: @Kyte Check again his code. I see that he's TRYING to compile something t hat would return him a Rational<int>. It would seem that he's only interested in that, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Felipe: My guess went long the lines of: "I want to have operator* for Rational<T>, but I don't know how. So in the meantime I'll just define it for Rational<int>".

Comment: @Kyte Yeah well, he wrote it like that when he was showing us the class, so I assumed he wanted that method like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't compile is explained by the compiler error. The containing type is a generic type definition, and a generic type *constructed* from such a type is not considered to be the same type.

I have a few questions:

1. Why must the `Rational` type be generic? A rational number is *defined* as a number that can be expressed as the quotient / fraction of two *integers* (where the denominator is not `0`). Why not make the type non-generic and simply use `int` throughout? Or do you intend that the type be used for other integral types such as `long` and `BigInteger`? In that case, consider using something like Aliostad's suggestion if you want some code-sharing mechanism.
2. Why do you want the product of two rational numbers to be the equal to the sum of their numerators over the sum of their denominators? That doesn't make sense to me.

---

In any case, you appear to want to be able to 'generically' add two instances of an 'addable' type. Unfortunately, there currently isn't any way to express a 'has a suitable addition operator' constraint in C#.

**Method #1:** One workaround for this in C# 4 is to use  the `dynamic` type to give you the desired "virtual operator" semantics.

```
public static Racional<T> operator *(Racional<T> a, Racional<T> b)
{
    var nominatorSum = (dynamic)a.Nominator + b.Nominator;
    var denominatorSum = (dynamic)a.Denominator + b.Denominator;

    return new Racional<T>(nominatorSum, denominatorSum);
}
```

The operator will throw if the type doesn't have a suitable addition operator.

---

**Method #2:** Another (more efficient) way is to use expression-trees.

First, create and cache a delegate that can perform the addition by compiling the appropriate expression:

```
private readonly static Func<T, T, T> Adder;

static Racional()
{
    var firstOperand = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var secondOperand = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "y");
    var body = Expression.Add(firstOperand, secondOperand);
     Adder = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>
                (body, firstOperand, secondOperand).Compile();    
}
```

(The static constructor will throw if the type doesn't have a suitable addition operator.)

Then employ it in the operator:

```
public static Racional<T> operator *(Racional<T> a, Racional<T> b)
{
    var nominatorSum = Adder(a.Nominator, b.Nominator);
    var denominatorSum = Adder(a.Denominator, b.Denominator);
    return new Racional<T>(nominatorSum, denominatorSum);
}
```

Comment: +1, very interesting that this is possible in a generic way. First time I got a notion of what expression trees are good for.

Comment: Good, why not int in all code: becouse i have such lab for my programming lesson

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you are defining an operator for `Racional<int>` in the class `Racional<T>`. This is not possible. **The types are not the same, you can only define operator for `Racional<T>`.**

*Generics cannot express generalization of operators since they are defined only for a certain types.* Solution is to create a class and inherit from `Racional<int>`:

```
public class IntRacional : Racional<int>
{
    public static Racional<int> operator +(IntRacional a, IntRacional b)
    {
        return new Racional<int>()
        {
            Nominator = a.Nominator + b.Nominator,
            Denominator = a.Denominator + b.Denominator
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Racional<T> and Racional<int> are two different classes in the eyes of the compiler. And you cant redefine the behaviour of one class in another (extension methods excluded).

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you need to provide conversion functions from `T` to some type where `operator+` is defined and vice versa. Assuming `Int64` is big enough in most cases, this can be done this way:

```
public class Racional<T> 
{
    private T nominator;
    private T denominator;
    static Converter<T,Int64> T_to_Int64;
    static Converter<Int64,T> Int64_to_T;

    public static void InitConverters(Converter<T,Int64> t2int, Converter<Int64,T> int2t )
    {
        T_to_Int64 = t2int;
        Int64_to_T = int2t;
    }

    public T Nominator
    {
        get { return nominator; }
        set { nominator = value; }
    }
    public T Denominator
    {
        get { return denominator; }
        set { denominator = value; }
    }
    public Racional(T nominator, T denominator)
    {
        this.nominator = nominator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
    public static Racional<T> operator *(Racional<T> a, Racional<T> b) 
    {
        return new Racional<T>(
            Int64_to_T(T_to_Int64(a.nominator) + T_to_Int64(b.nominator)),
            Int64_to_T(T_to_Int64(a.denominator) + T_to_Int64(b.denominator)));
    }

    // By the way, should this not be * instead of + ???
    //
    // public static Racional<T> operator *(Racional<T> a, Racional<T> b) 
    // {
    //    return new Racional<T>(
    //        Int64_to_T(T_to_Int64(a.nominator) * T_to_Int64(b.nominator)),
    //        Int64_to_T(T_to_Int64(a.denominator) * T_to_Int64(b.denominator)));
    // }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + this.nominator + " " + this.denominator + ")";
    }
}
```

Of course, this has the drawback that you must provide the initialization of those converters somewhere at the program start, should look like this:

```
Racional<int>.InitConverters(x => (Int64)x, y => (int)y);
```

In a real program, you may know which possible replacements for `T` you are going to use. So one can provide those 3 or 4 calls in a static constructor like this:

```
    public static Racional()
    {
        Racional<int>.InitConverters(x => (Int64)x, y => (int)y);
        Racional<short>.InitConverters(x => (Int64)x, y => (short)y);
        Racional<Int64>.InitConverters(x => (Int64)x, y => (Int64)y);
    }
```

should be sufficient in most cases. Note that this converter initialization is repeated for all 3 types 3 times again, re-initializing the conversion functions multiple times again. In practice this should not make any trouble.

Comment: virtual -1. A bad guess!! Does not compile with error `One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type`

Comment: @Aliostad: changed my answer completely.